# datatables responsive rowcallback

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, datatables, angular-datatables

I use datatable V1.10 and angular-datatables V7

My data table shows 3 action buttons (edit, delete, read).

[image]

It works nice

But in a responsive mode like the following :

[image]

it fails :

this is the code for display buttons:

```
  columnDefs: [
                {
                    orderable: false,
                    // className: 'my_class', // classname définit une checkbox par dessus une case vide [object Object] (data: null)
                    targets: [0],
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return'<input type="checkbox" class="unique-class mat-checkbox mat-accent mat-checkbox-anim-checked-unchecked ' +
                            'mat-checkbox-inner-container mat-checkbox-inner-container-no-side-margin">';
                    }
                },
                {
                    targets: [4],
                    visible: true,
                    data: 'action',
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        console.log(type);
                        return '<a id="id" class="btn btn-link btn-success btn-just-icon btn-edit" title="Editer">' +
                            '<i class="material-icons">create</i></a>' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-link btn-danger btn-just-icon btn-remove" title="Supprimer">' +
                            '<i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-link btn-info btn-just-icon btn-read" title="Consulter">' +
                            '<i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a>'
                    }
                }
            ],
```

And for rowCallback events :

```
rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
                const self = this;
                console.log(row);
                console.log($('td:hidden', row).find('a.btn-edit'));
                console.log($('td', row).find('a.btn-edit'));
                // Unbind first in order to avoid any duplicate handler
                // (see https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/87)
                // $('td:first-child', row).unbind('click');
                // $('td:first-child', row).bind('click', () => {
                const elt = $('td', row).find('[type="checkbox"]');
                if (elt) {
                    elt.unbind('click');
                    elt.bind('click', () => {
                        if (elt[0].checked) {
                            that.selectedList.push(data as Contact)
                        } else {
                            const itemIndex = this.selectedList.indexOf(data as Contact);
                            that.selectedList.splice(itemIndex, 1);
                        }
                        console.log(that.selectedList.length + ' éléments sélectionés');
                        this.selectedList.forEach((item) => {
                            console.log(item)
                        })
                    });
                }
                const eltedit = $('td', row).find('a.btn-edit');
                if (eltedit) {
                    console.log('trouvé td');
                    eltedit.unbind('click');
                    eltedit.bind('click', () => {
                        console.log(data);
                        this.crudContact(data, 2);
                    });
                }
                const eltedit2 = $('td:hidden', row).find('a.btn-edit');
                console.log($('#id').css('display'));
                if (eltedit2) {
                    console.log('trouvé td hidden');
                    eltedit2.unbind('click');
                    eltedit2.bind('click', () => {
                        console.log(data);
                        this.crudContact(data, 2);
                    });
                }
```

- eltedit contant works
- eltedit2 constant for responsive mode fails.

When I inspect elements, I notice that in responsive mode,
display: none attribute appears :

[image]

I think that it's this attribute that avoids click event detection...

How to solve that?

**EDIT**
I have added log like this

```
const eltedit2 = $('td:hidden', row).find('a.btn-edit');
console.log($('td:hidden', row).find('a.btn-edit').length);
```

and the length value is 1, so the element is found.
So I suppose the problem comes from "unbind" function

**EDIT 2**
If I change

```
if (eltedit2) {
                    console.log('trouvé td hidden');
                    eltedit2.unbind('click');
                    eltedit2.bind('click', () => {
                        console.log(data);
                        this.crudContact(data, 2);
                    });
                }
```

by :

```
if (eltedit2) {
                console.log('trouvé td hidden');
                $('table').unbind('click');
                $('table').bind('click', () => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.crudContact(data, 2);
                });
            }
```

It works except that it's always the last record that is selected...

Answer (score 0):

I have found this helpfull link http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/891mdyvy/1/

and I get now the solution to manage my data base in responsive mode and in web mode

First point in columnDefs part, add data attribute like this :

```
{
   targets: [4],
   visible: true,
   data: 'action',
   render: function(data, type, full: Contact, meta) {
   const contact = JSON.stringify(data).split('"').join('\'');
   return '<a data-contact="'+ contact + '" class="btn btn-link btn-success btn-just-icon btn-edit" title="Editer">' +
          '<i class="material-icons">create</i></a>' +
          '<a data-contact="' + contact + '"  class="btn btn-link btn-danger btn-just-icon btn-remove" title="Supprimer">' +
          '<i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>' +
          '<a data-contact="' + contact + '" class="btn btn-link btn-info btn-just-icon btn-read" title="Consulter">' +
          '<i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a>'
    }
}
```

2nd point, in rowCallback point , detect click event and retrieve data content like this:

```
$('table').unbind('click');
$("table").on('click','a.btn-edit', function () {
     console.log(JSON.parse($(this).data('contact').split('\'').join('"')));
     // ..your process..
});
$("table").on('click','a.btn-remove', function () {
     console.log(JSON.parse($(this).data('contact').split('\'').join('"')));
     // ..your process..
});
$("table").on('click','a.btn-read', function () {
     console.log(JSON.parse($(this).data('contact').split('\'').join('"')));
     // ..your process..
});
```

It works both in responsive mode and "web" mode